# Application exit when trying to call when no sim card exists

Tags: iphone, call

I am using tel:%@ to call from my application. when there is no sim card in the device.The application exists showing no sim card installed alert. I don't want my application to exit,how to handle that. I found in one of the answers to set exit(0); in - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application  . But its not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `UIApplication canOpenURL:` to determine whether opening the URL will work. This will return `NO` if you are on a device that doesn't support making calls (e.g., iPad or iPod Touch). It may also return `NO` if there is no SIM card installed.

Comment: No it is not working application still exists trying to call the no. and then device native alert comes of sim not installed. :(\

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the app to exit, you have to use a UIWebView to invoke your call. This could be an example:

```
UIWebView *callWebview = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

NSString *phoneNumber = [[NSString stringWithString:@"tel:123456789"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];        
NSURL *phoneURL = [NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber];
[callWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:phoneURL]];
```

I use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` just in case I include some special characters I want to parse.

If you don't have a SIM installed, it will just return to the same view in which was invoked.